# No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'appendData'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to call the server asynchronously (ARC -on):

```
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if (theConnection) {
    content = [NSMutableData data];
    NSLog(@"responseData from setup.php: %@", content);
} else {        
    // Inform the user that the connection failed.
    NSLog(@"error from server response in set up");
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"connection did receive response");
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [content appendData:data];

    NSLog(@"connection did receive data");
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
   NSLog(@"connection did finish load");
   NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %@ bytes of data",receivedData);
}
```

But i am having problem getting the content from the server:-
in didReceiveData function, following error is coming:-
No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'appendData'

Can anybody suggest me where I could be wrong?

Comment: As your error states - you are trying to call appendData method from the object of class NSString. As there is no such method you're getting error..check the type of content obj

Comment: where have u declared the variable "content"

Comment: I HAVE declared it globally like this: NSString *content;

Comment: but NSString does not have such method!!??

Comment: what do you actually want to do ?

Comment: Yes i changed that declaration to NSMutableData *content; and it worked.But the main problem is when i try to print(log) the received data in 'connectionDidFinishLoading' function, it is showing something like this: 0a0a0a27 3c62722f 3e3c6272 2f3e3c62 722f3e3c 62722f3e 3c63656e 7465723e 3c683420, instead of characters(i am printing some characters on the server, which i need to use in client)

Comment: try this..in connectionDidFinishLoading  NSString *response = [[[NSString alloc]initWithData:content encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

Comment: Thanks a lot @AppleDelegate and stats, i am really new to objective-C, so was asking basic questions. I really appreciate your help. Loads of thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your .h  file in the interface section please declare the following

```
NSMutableData *content;
```