# new to ios - not able to assign string to property

Tags: ios, objective-c

in my .m file i created the following property:

```
@property(strong) NSString *var;
```

I tried to assign a string to it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

   [self.var getstring];

}//viewDidLoad

-(NSString *)getstring{


    return @"hello";

}
```

but it gave me the error "no visible @interface for NSString declares the selector getString

Comment: `self.var` itself gives the string assigned to it.

Comment: Full syntax:  `[self setVar:[self getString]];`. Easy syntax `self.var = [self getString];`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'appendData'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418715/no-visible-interface-for-nsstring-declares-the-selector-appenddata)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[self.var getstring]
```

The code above sends a message/ "calls" the getstring selector/"method" in var, which has a type of `NSString`. `NSString` has no such selector which explains your error:

> no visible @interface for `NSString` declares the selector getString

To assign the result of `getstring` to the property `var`, you would write:

```
self.var = [self getstring];
```

**NOTE**

Objective-C discourages prepending methods with get. You could call your method `-(NSString *) helloString`

Comment: i dont understand what you mean by "NSString has no such selector "

Comment: If you're new to Objective-C, you can suppose that a method and a selector are the same thing (they're not actually). What the error message is saying is that the class NSString does not define a "method" called getstring.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

   self.var = [self getstring];

}//viewDidLoad

-(NSString *)getstring{
    return @"hello";
}
```

> Function call into same ViewController for that time we uses [self
>   methodName] if return any some value then need to catch that value
>   with "=" to assign a value.

So that here you need to replace this code `[self.var getstring];` with `self.var = [self getstring];`

Comment: How is this going to work, I just edited your code

Answer (score 0):

you just need to do assign the string

`self.var = [self getstring]` instead:

`[self.var getstring];`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that these square brackets mean "send a message to this object"(obj-c msg send). What do you do? You send a message to your var. Your var is an instance of Nsstring class which in turn does not have method called getstring. That is what error actually says. So, my thoughts are:

1. The correct way to assign a string to your var is self.var = [self getstring]
2. It is better to use camel style coding. So the method name looks like getString

Answer (score 0):

When you not use @synthesize,the getter and setter method is not rewrite.In other words,you can only use system's getter and setter method.But when you use @synthesize,you can rewrite the getter and setter method.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property(nonatomic)NSString *age;
@end

@implementation ViewController


@synthesize age = _age;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

}
-(void)setAge:(NSString *)age {
    _age = age;
}
-(NSString *)age
{
    return _age;
}

@end
```